# Android. How to use pagination with clean architecture?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, clean-architecture, android-mvvm, android-paging-3

I'm writing application with `MVVM` and clean architecture. On one of the screens I need to implement `RecyclerView` with `pagination`. I am going to use the library `Paging3`.

Android Developer recommends using `PagingSource` and `RemoteMediator` in repository layer. But at the same time, in many sources, I read that the data layer and the domain layer should not know anything about the android framework.

But now I have to use the android library in the data sources of my data layer. Is this correct in the context of a `clean architecture`?

Please help me figure it out, I don't understand how to implement pagination using clean architecture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paging library is split into multiple artifacts. There is `paging-common`, which is a pure kotlin library that contains `PagingSource` and `RemoteMediator` among others. Then, there is a `paging-runtime` which is an android library that wires paging sources with `RecyclerView` and `paging-compose`, another android library that does the same for Jetpack Compose UI.

That means that you can use `paging-common` in a pure kotlin module and in your repositories just fine, there is no android specific code in there. You can even use that repository on different platform, if you write that platform specific wiring yourself.